# Is there a possibility to have a quiver plot with vectors of same length?

Tags: matlab

I am using a quiver plot in MATLAB to simulate a velocity field. Now I would like the vectors produced by the quiver plot to be all the same length, so that they just indicate the vectors direction. The value of the velocity in each point should be illustrated by different colors then.
Is there a possibility to have quiver plotting vectors of same length?

That's my current code:

```
%defining parameters:
age = 900;
vis= 15;

turbulences = zeros(9,3);
a = 0.01;
spacing = 1000;
[x,y] = meshgrid(-100000:spacing:100000);%, 0:spacing:10000);
u = a;
v = 0;

n = 0;
for i = 1:4
    turbulences(i,1) = -80000 + n;
    turbulences(i,2) = 15000;
    n = 15000 * i; 
end

n = 0;
for i = 5:9
    turbulences(i,1) = -15000 + n*5000;
    turbulences(i,2) = 4000;
    n = n+1;
end

for i = 1:4
    turbulences(i,3) = -1000;
end
for i = 5:9
    turbulences(i,3) = 800;
end

%compute velocities in x and y direction 
for k = 1:9
    xc = turbulences(k,1);
    yc = turbulences(k,2);
    r1 = ((x-xc).^2 + (y-yc).^2);
    r2 = ((x-xc).^2 + (y+yc).^2);
    u = u + turbulences(k,3)/2*pi * (((y-yc)./r1).*(1-exp(-(r1./(4*vis*age)))) - ((y+yc)./r2).*(1-exp(-(r2./(4*vis*age)))));
    v = v - turbulences(k,3)/2*pi* (((x-xc)./r1).*(1-exp(-(r1./(4*vis*age)))) - ((x-xc)./r2).*(1-exp(-(r2./(4*vis*age)))));
end

quiver(x,y,u,v);
grid on;
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `quiver(x, y, u./abs(u), v./abs(v))`?

Comment: good idea, thanks!

Comment: Added as answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to normalize each component of your vectors to +- 1 just to keep their direction.

```
un = u./abs(u); % normalized u
vn = v./abs(v); % normalized v
quiver(x, y, un, vn)
```

Comment: as u and v are not independent from each other I used: ```value = sqrt(u.^2 + v.^2); quiver(x,y,u./betrag,v./betrag); ``` Thank you!